# Can I use a WCF client proxy as a straight replacement for SoapHttpClientProtocol?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I'm talking with a web service with a generated proxy that uses *System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol*, is there any reason I might have trouble replacing the proxy with a WCF client proxy?

The web service being called is written in Java and uses the Apache Axis SOAP engine.  It uses only HTTP Basic authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an underlying issue that you're trying to solve by making this change?  I've issues doing something like this in the past.

Comment: Yes we are seeing very high latency on simple ping method calls. We tracked this down to something in SoapHttpClientProtocol's stack sending the headers in one packet and waiting for the ACK response before sending the body of the request.  This doubles the latency of the call for us.  Java clients don't exhibit this problem, we want to try a WCF client to see if it behaves better.

Comment: Hmm, how far away are these machines?  I've never had an issue with normal or WCF web service clients accessing all types of web services.  

I don't think you're going to solve your issue this way, but you can try. 

For how to do it, you can adapt the following scenario to your example, just follow what he says about the reference.cs file and the 2 configs. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283374/how-to-add-a-service-reference-to-a-wcf-client-for-a-web-service-requiring-client