# WCF NETCORE ERROR, Unable to create an SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi, wcf-binding

I'm trying to connect to a Web Service with two-way ssl auth, I've installed the certificates to consume, in the browser in the browser asks me for the certificate and then access the web service [photo: accessing the web service from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7PId.png).

but when i try add the reference to a class library project in WCF Reference trow me this message: `An error occurred while attempting to find services at 'https://ws.interbanking.com.ar/ws/ConsultaCuentaClienteService?wsdl'. Request cancelled: Unable to create an SSL/TLS secure channel.`   
[Photo: error message in vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQHjU.png)
I tried to download the file that I generated the browser when I give it the certificate and convert it to wsdl and add it but it did not work

any solution?

Comment: This seems to be similar, does it help? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283374/how-to-add-a-service-reference-to-a-wcf-client-for-a-web-service-requiring-clien

Comment: in soapUI I went to Files ->Preferences -> SSL Settings add the certificate in keystore and the password and it worked. some way to specify that in vs to consume the ws?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.